# Override up button material design android

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to use material design in android

I'd like to override this button at action bar

[image]

This button back to a parent activity defined on Manifest by this code

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
    </activity>
```

I call MainActivity from various others activities, so, I'd like to override this button and just execute `activity.finish()`, so it's always come back an activity and not to the activity defined on Manifest.

How can I do it? Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I did it!

I removed the parent activity on Manifest and on my activity I did:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but it works for me!